# Counting occurrences and making calculations with a dataframe

Tags: julia, julia-dataframe

I have column in a dataframe like this:

```
df = DataFrame(:num=>rand(0:10,20))
```

From `df` I want to make 2 others dataframe:

df1 = counter(df[!,:num)

To have the frequencies of each integer from `0 to 10`. But I need the values **sorted** from 0 to 10:

```
0=>2
1=>3
2=>7
```

so on..

Then I want a new dataframe `df2` where:

```
column_p = sum of occurrences of 9 and 10
column_n = sum of occurrences of 7 and 8
column_d = sum of occurrences of 0 to 6
```

I managed to get the first part, even though the result is not sorted but this last dataframe has been a challenge to my julia skills (still learning)

**UPDATE 1**

I managed to do this fucntion:

```
function f(dff)

@eachrow dff begin
    
    if     :num >=9
           :class = "Positive"
    elseif :num >=7
           :class = "Neutral"
    elseif :num <7 
           :class = "Negative"   
    end  
end
end
```

This function do half of what I want and fails if there's no `:class` column in the dataframe.

Now I want to count how many `positive, neutral and negatives` to do this operation:

```
(posivite - negative) / (negatives+neutral+positives)
```

Comment: but this is not the answer yet.  It's just part of what I am trying.

Answer (score 2):

The first part is:

```
julia> using DataFrames, Random

julia> Random.seed!(1234);

julia> df = DataFrame(:num=>rand(0:10,20));

julia> df1 = combine(groupby(df, :num, sort=true), nrow)
10×2 DataFrame
 Row │ num    nrow
     │ Int64  Int64
─────┼──────────────
   1 │     0      1
   2 │     2      2
   3 │     3      2
   4 │     4      2
   5 │     5      1
   6 │     6      2
   7 │     7      2
   8 │     8      4
   9 │     9      1
  10 │    10      3
```

I was not sure what you wanted in the second step, but here are two ways to achieve the third step using either `df1` or `df`:

```
julia> (sum(df1.nrow[df1.num .>= 9]) - sum(df1.nrow[df1.num .<= 6])) / sum(df1.nrow)
-0.3

julia> (count(>=(9), df.num) - count(<=(6), df.num)) / nrow(df)
-0.3
```